# How do I set the environment in a Visual Studio generated publish profile

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have 2 publish profiles. I want to make one staging and one production. After browsing a bit I found out you could use the command line publish to set an environment variable: `dotnet publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:EnvironmentName=Staging`. However my publish profiles are generated by Visual Studio and I was wondering if I could set it in there?

Comment: are you going to deploy it on IIS?

Comment: Yes. It is a self-contained app. Sadly though I do not have any access to the server beyond publishing. So I cannot set an environment variable on the server itself.

Comment: can you connect your IIS instance or site remotely?

Comment: No. I can only do a filetransfer to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't tried this approach on .Net Core, I believe that It will work since It is the feature of VS Publish (msbuild).

you need to create web.config. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:30:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
      <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

then you need to add **Config Transform** for these (see below)

[image: Config Transformation]

[image: Config Transformation Menu Position]

For the config transformation you can check this github documentation: https://github.com/vijayrkn/webconfigtransform/blob/master/README.md

then you need to transform your publish profile as well.

`web.$(publish-profile-name).config` is going to be your web.config name. You need to change environment variables of the transformed web.configs respectively.

Comment: Where do you set up what environment do you want to use in the publish profile? How does the visual studio know, what web.config to use?